# Graph theory: proving that a trail exists when an edge is removed from a circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> If vertices v and w are part of a circuit in G and one edge is removed from the circuit, then there still exists a trail from v to w.

I'm trying to prove this statement, but I don't know how to express it mathematically. I know how to explain it intuitively - if you remove an edge, you can go "the other way around" since it's a circuit - but how can I reason it in a mathematical way?

Answer (score 2):

Consider decomposing the circuit in two trails from $v $ to $w $. When you remove one edge, can you destroy both trails simultaneously?